# Liquid in rotating cylinder and many confusions related to fluid mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I am a  high school student and I am very confused in fluid mechanics, MY confusion is that:

1. we know pressure increases with depth, but I want to know what are the cause and effect here **i,e actually pressure depends on height or height depends upon pressure?** because in some cases if we have to explain why liquid surface tilts when liquids are subjected to some acceleration then most people explains it by saying that pressure will increase as we move in opposite direction to the acceleration, so the height will gradually increase over them.
2. I have heard that ***ideal fluids cannot hold shear stress i.e if their surface is subjected to some net force then the surface molecules will start to flow in that direction, but I want to know whether the force on each and every particle present on the surface should be 0 along the surface or the net force on the surface as a whole should be zero along the surface?*** and I want to know whether they mean that the surface particles will start gaining some speed in the direction of force, if yes, then ***what if those particles already have some velocity which is always perpendicular to the force acting along the surface on them, in this case this they will not gain speed in the direction of force instead they will always move in a circle*** [image: this image shows the shape of the meniscus in a rotating cylinder]
3. I am very confused when we rotate the liquid contained in a cylindrical vessel, why the surface changes its shape here? I mean what are the real forces acting on the surface which makes the surface look like the way it is, I can derive the mathematical equation for this curve I know it is a Parabola so, please don't derive it for me, I just want to know it intuitively by considering only real forces, that why this surface tilts here { *I know we cannot explain the shape intuitively, I just want to know why it tilts that's all , I don't care about the shape*}

If anyone could possibly explain it without involving higher mathematics, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you accept the following ideas:  1.  The pressure at all locations on the curved surface is the same, and equal to atmospheric pressure.  2.  All fluid particles are traveling in circles with the same angular velocity about the axis at all locations within the fluid>

Comment: yes, I accept them ,, I want to know what forces makes this kind of shape, I know that pressure varies radially when we rotate it, due to this the height increases, but in some places it is also written that IDEAL fluids cannot hold tangential force so the surface will tilt like when we accelerate it,i don't understand how it tilts due to this reason?

Comment: Once the fluid rotation is established, there are negligible viscous forces acting.  The forces that are acting after the rotation is established are only gravitational and pressure forces.  These forces combine with the tilt of the free surface to provide the net forces to accelerate the fluid radially inward to allow the fluid movement in circles.